# How To Check bits in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, clion, unary-operator

In C++ I wrote:

```
bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0x00000000000000FF) == 0x000000000000050f;
```

but clion says it's always wrong, why?

I am trying to check if last 4 are `0x050f`

Comment: The last 4 will never bet `0x050F` because you've masked off to just the last 8 bits.

Comment: If by last 4, you mean 4 hex digits you'll need OxFFFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that the least-significant 2 bytes of `ret_inst_data` have exactly the value `0x050F`, then you need to use a mask of `0xFFFF`:

```
bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0xFFFF) == 0x050F;
```

---

As for why your original comparison is incorrect, let's look at just the least-significant two bytes of the numbers involved.

- `0x050F` has the bit pattern `0000 0101 0000 1111`
- `0x00FF` has the bit pattern `0000 0000 1111 1111`

If we bitwise and those two patterns together, we get the bit pattern

```
  0000 0101 0000 1111
& 0000 0000 1111 1111
---------------------
  0000 0000 0000 1111
```

The binary `0000 0000 0000 1111` is `0x000F` in hex.

As you can see, because the second-least-significant-byte of `0x00FF` is all `0`s, the result of performing a bitwise and between `0x00FF` and any number will produce a result with a second-least-significant-byte of all `0`s.  Since the second-least-significant byte of `0x050F` is not all `0`s your comparison can never be true.

Answer (score 2):

Masking with `0xFF` leaves only 8 bits available to look at, but `0x50f` takes up 11 bits.  So the comparison can never be true.

If you are only interested in the last 4 **bits**, use a mask of `0x0f` instead:

```cpp
bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0x000000000000000f) == 0x000000000000000f;
```

Otherwise, you need a mask of **at least** `0x7FF` (11 bits) in order to compare with `0x50f`:

```cpp
bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0x00000000000007ff) == 0x000000000000050f;
```

If you are interested in the last 4 **hex digits** (16 bits), use a mask of `0xffff` instead:

```cpp
bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0x000000000000ffff) == 0x000000000000050f;
```

Comment: plus I am interested in last 4 digits in hexa and don't care about other digits what they will be, which one to use? so anything ends like this 050f is correct to me otherwise false

Comment: @debo "*where the 7 came from*" - if you need to ask that, you need to read up on what bits actually are and how they are represented in hex.

Comment: We can simply do: `bool ret_is_syscall = (ret_inst_data & 0xFFFF) == 0x050F;`